# Kendo ScatterLine Chart Notes

Tags: jquery, charts, kendo-ui, scatter-plot

I am trying to pass notes to kendo scatter line chart.

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  dataSource: {
    data: [{
      value: 1,
      noteText: "A",
      xField: 10
    },
           {
      value: 1,
      noteText: "A",
      xField: 12
    },
           {
      value: 1,      
      xField: 4
    },
           {
      value: 1,      
      xField: 4,
noteText: "A"             
    },
           {
      value: null,      
      xField: 2,
      noteText: "EventIndicator"             
    }]
  },
  seriesDefaults: {
    type: "scatterLine",
    noteTextField: "noteText"//,
                   // notes: {
                     //   label: {
                    //        visible: false
                    //    },
                    //    icon: {
                    //        size: 0,
                    //        visible: false,
                    //    },
                   //     line: {
                    //        length: 0,
                     //       width: 0,
                   //     },
                  //  }
  },
  series: [{   
    xField: "xField",
    yField: "value",
    noteTextField: "noteText"
  }]
});
```

I am able to get notes as per my code. Special requirement here is I have to just plot a note with out data point. If you can see for one of the data point I am passing value as null. So scatterline chart is not taking null to plot just a note for given xaxis value. So I need a way to figure this out. Even if there is way that I can pass notes apart from this. I am strictly looking for scatterline chart only. Please let me know if any one have an idea of workaround...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the marker visual property to hide markers that have noteText:

```
markers: {
    visual: function (e) {
      if (e.dataItem.noteText){
          return;
      } else {
          return e.createVisual();
      }
    }
  },
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/uJAca)**

If you actually don't want the line to go through that point and only want a note, you could just have a second series set to scatter (no line) and use the visual to hide the markers.